# Is This Data Model Meeting My Requirements?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a Razor Pages application that resembles a "hockey league". As I'm still grasping the concept of foreign/primary keys, I'm not quite sure if I'm setting up my data model correctly. After attempting to update my database after a migration I am getting the following error that has led me to believe I didn't set them up correctly:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Team_Division_DivisionID' on table 'Team' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Based on these three entities, am I clearly doing something wrong?

```
public class Team
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? CoachID { get; set; }
    public int? DivisionID { get; set; }
    public int? ConferenceID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Team")]
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public string TeamLocation { get; set; }

    public Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public Division Division { get; set; }
    public Conference Conference { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Conference
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Conference")]
    public string ConferenceName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }        
}

public class Division
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ConferenceID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Division")]
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }

    public Conference Conference { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }

}
```

My idea is that every `Team` will belong to a `Conference` and a `Division`. There can be many `Teams` in a `Division`, and many `Divisions` in a `Conference`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that SQL server doesn't know how to handle a `Delete` of an item that has multiple parents.  You'll need to help it out a bit.  Choose a route that you want `Team` to be deleted on, for instance:

```
Conference --> Division --> Team
```

Then you must determine the routes that you *don't* want it to be deleted on, for instance:

```
Conference --> Team
```

Once you've decided which routes *won't* be used for deletion, you can specify it in the `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method for your context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Conference>() 
    .HasRequired(x => x.Team)     
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**EDIT**

Pretty sure I got that backwards above, try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>() 
    .HasRequired(x => x.Conference)     
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Is there a reason I would be getting an error saying: 'EntityTypeBuilder<Team>' does not contain a definition for 'HasRequired' and no accessible extension method 'HasRequired' accepting a first parameter of type 'EntityTypeBuilder<Team>' could be found

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: EFCore 2.1.1, I believe

Comment: Looks like EFCore differs slightly here.  Try `HasOne`.